# Phoenix Presence: How to rename "presence_diff" to something more domain specific?

Tags: phoenix-framework, phoenix-channels

Phoenix has a nice event for broadcasting presence changes called `presence_diff`. I've tried to find a way to rename this event to something more specific to my domain (`agent_diff` in my case).

Does anyone know if there's an idiomatic way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution I came up with, please let me know if you have a better approach

```
intercept ["presence_diff"]
def handle_out("presence_diff", msg, socket) do
  push(socket, "agent_diff", msg)
  {:noreply, socket}
end
```